# Expressing "would rather do X"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure out how to express the following idea in English in Japanese:

> "I would rather listen to music."

The context would be something like speaking colloquially with a friend, saying something beforehand along the lines of "I don't cook much because I'm lazy".

I am not sure if there is a direct translation for this.  Would this be correct?:

> ”怠惰からよく料理をしないね．．．音楽を聞くの方がいい”

Comment: Does that sound natural in English in the given scenario? Is listening to music something you would rather do instead of cooking? I have some ideas about how to translate “would rather” but I wouldn’t say none of them in your scenario.

Comment: @aguijonazo I don't know that it sounds *natural* or not.  But it does certainly seem like a weird choice:  cook or listen to music?  Why not do both, right.  It seems like the choices should be comparable.